# How can I center a background image on a web page for different screen resolutions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to determine the screen resolution of the client machine and the set the background image in the center using JavaScript.

I have come so far:

```
function centerBackGroundImage()
{
    var browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    $("#background").css({ "z-index": "-10", "margin:left": (browserWidth / 2) - (browserHeight/ 2) });
}
```

I have already added the div tag named `background` and the `<img>` tag with the location of the image file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. You can do it using just CSS [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position):

```
#background {
     background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TqPNF/) - It'll work inside an element as well, not just `body` as in my example.

Comment: ... along with `background-image: url(...)`

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, thanks... I thought that was obvious but it may not be since I was proposing a completely different solution.

Comment: i tried that, but still its not coming to the center of the page

Comment: @patel.milanb in itself, the code works. We'll need to see more code to see what could be conflicting with it in your page.

Comment: i am using this css 
.mainBackgroundImage img { /*width:100%; height:100%;*/ padding:0 auto 0 auto; position:fixed; padding-right:800px; background-position:center; z-index:-10; margin-left: 165px; }
this is working fine ..BUT want to have javascript that can set the image in the center

Comment: The code is for a `background-image` You don't apply it to an `img` tag. Try using the code in my answer, just changing `#background` to `.mainBackgroundImage` and the `url` to your image.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you cross browser resolution

```
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
```